# sub domain help

Tags: domain, virtualhost, apache-2.2

**UPDATE 2:**

I've create a new "A record" instead as I couldn't get the "cname record" to work.  I copied the existing:

```
www - A - server_ip_address
```

and just created a new

```
test - A - server_ip_address
```

But when I type

```
host test.oshirowanen.com
```

It can't find it, but it finds

```
host www.oshirowanen.com perfectly ok.
```

Do I need to wait for the new record to propagate the internet?

**UPDATE 1:**

On the DNS config screen, I get the following options

```
Type: (Which has CNAME)
Record (Which is a textbox)
Domain (Which is a textbox)
```

**ORIGINAL QUESITON:**

If I have already purchased the domain name:

```
oshirowanen.com
```

and I wanted to configure a sub domain which points to a different section of my website i.e.

```
login.oshirowanen.com
```

will I have to buy a new domain name, i.e.

```
login.oshirowanen.com
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is create a [CNAME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) login.oshirowanen.com record in your DNS that points to oshirowanen.com. How you do this depends on what access you have to the DNS system.

```
login.oshirowanen.com.        CNAME  oshirowanen.com.
oshirowanen.com.              A      ip.add.re.ss
```

EDIT:

Iin the 3 boxes you have

1. Leave type as CNAME
2. Make Record login.oshirowanen.com
3. Make Domain oshirowanen.com

If that doesn't work then 2 & 3 need to be switched.

Comment: Please see update 1 in the original question.

Comment: Please see update 2 in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You'll just need to go into your control panel and see if you can find a place to create subdomains.

Comment: Which control panel?  I have access to the dns system, if that is what you mean?

Comment: Depends on your hosting company and what they use. Examples include CPanel and 1and1's Control Panel. A list can be found http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_hosting_control_panels#Licence_and_Operating_system_support or visit your hosting companies support page for setting up subdomains.

Comment: Not sure if you mean the company hosting the website, or the company from which we buy our domain names from?

Comment: erk. My hosting company does both, but I'm going to say the one you've bought the domain from.

Comment: Please see update 1 in the original question.

Comment: Please see update 2 in the original question.